# Why should the size of the kernel be odd?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

When using the **mean filter** in image processing, why should the size of the *kernel* be **odd**? It Always takes a odd size as **3x3** or **5x5**. Could anyone explain it with reasons?

Comment: http://aishack.in/tutorials/convolutions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The kernel doesn't need to be odd. It's perfectly possible to define an even-sized kernel. When the kernel size is even, it is less obvious which of the pixels should be at the origin, but this is not a problem. You have seen mostly odd-sized filter kernels because they are symmetric around the origin, which is a good property.

Here is an example in MATLAB where we filter the image with a 4x4 averaging kernel (mean filter):

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
img = imfilter(img,fspecial('average',4));
imshow(img)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But the only purpose of using odd kernel, only because of it is symmetrical around the origin?Are there any other purposes.Could you explain it.

Comment: @Mash962: No, there is no other reason.

Comment: A non-symmetric kernel yields a non-symmetric filter response. In the example above, this non-symmetry leads to a shift of the blurred image by half a pixel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. There is a detailed answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23183/why-convolutions-always-use-odd-numbers-as-filter-size).