# Why is the filter size on a convolutional layer alway an odd number?

Tags: networking, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there a reason it always is 3x3 or 5x5 and never 4x4?

Comment: I found a good answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493590/why-should-the-size-of-the-kernel-be-odd#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20kernel%20doesn't%20need%20to%20be%20odd.&text=When%20the%20kernel%20size%20is,which%20is%20a%20good%20property..). Basically the kernel doesn't need to be odd it can be even, but odd kernels are better at showing which pixels are the origin of the image.

Comment: Thank you very much